# Why does a MySQL not recognize a table value?

Tags: mysql

Friends

For some reason, a MySQL query refuses to recognize a particular value in a table.

The table contains columns

```
"idLookUp", "LUgroup", "LUvalue" 
212 adispo AdmICU_Interv
213 adispo AdmICU_noInterv

SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE LUvalue = "AdmICU_Interv";
```

returns no records!

```
SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE LUvalue = "AdmICU_noInterv";
```

returns the proper record (#212).

```
SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE idLookUp = 212
```

returns the proper record

The string AdmICU_Interv doesn't figure anywhere else and is not a reserved phrase (from what I can tell). I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here, but I can't figure out what is causing this behavior.

I'd appreciate any hints. Thx!

jon

Comment: Check for whitespace you may not be noticing, or non-printing characters that may not show up normally. A good first check is to see if LENGTH() value corresponds to what you expect. It is not uncommon to end up with trailing/leading newlines/tabs in data when input filters are not catching such things.

Answer (score 0):

could you have some hidden char try using trim()

```
SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE trim(LUvalue) = "AdmICU_Interv";
```

or like

```
SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE LUvalue like "%AdmICU_Interv%";
```

Answer (score 0):

and this:

SELECT * FROM LookUp WHERE LUvalue LIKE "%AdmICU_Interv%"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Folks, very helpful. Yes, there was something in there I could not see. Still don't know what. Length was 13 when it should have been 12. Overwriting with the correct string solved the problem.

Since this was a lookup table, I have to go back and update all records with the problematic entry, but MySQL does that easily:

UPDATE LookUp SET LUvalue = 'AdmICU_Interv' WHERE LUvalue LIKE "%AdmICU_Interv%";

I do appreciate the problem solving hints. Hope this helps somebody else.

Cheers

Jon